# Cannot find working mvvmcross 4.x Mac Xamarin example code

Tags: macos, mvvmcross, xamarin-studio, monomac, xamarin.mac

I'd like to get some simple sample app running for MvvmCross 4.x version for Xamarin.Mac on a Mac using Xamarin Studio. Apparently Mac is supported in the nuget packages in version 4.x. The TipCalc app has most platforms but is missing Xamarin.Mac. Any examples I've found are only for 3.x versions and even those I'm unable to get to run on a Mac with Xamarin Studio. The TipCalc is ideal for me because it has iOS, Android, Windows but is just missing a Mac example.

The error I'm getting when I compile what I have now for TipCalc Mac is as follows. Does anyone have ideas of how I can get this working?

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>     at MvvmCross.Platform.Mvx.Resolve[TService] () [0x00005] in V:\Xamarin\MvvmCross\MvvmCross\Platform\Platform\Mvx.cs:34
>     at MvvmCross.Mac.Views.MvxViewControllerExtensionMethods.LoadViewModel (MvvmCross.Mac.Views.IMvxMacView macView) [0x0001b] in /Users/kwl/Projects/Xamarin/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/Mac/Mac/Views/MvxViewControllerExtensionMethods.cs:38
>     at MvvmCross.Mac.Views.MvxViewControllerExtensionMethods+c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () [0x00000] in /Users/kwl/Projects/Xamarin/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/Mac/Mac/Views/MvxViewControllerExtensionMethods.cs:24
>     at MvvmCross.Core.Views.MvxViewExtensionMethods.OnViewCreate (MvvmCross.Core.Views.IMvxView view, System.Func`1[TResult] viewModelLoader) [0x00012] in :0
>     at MvvmCross.Mac.Views.MvxViewControllerExtensionMethods.OnViewCreate (MvvmCross.Mac.Views.IMvxMacView macView) [0x0000d] in /Users/kwl/Projects/Xamarin/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/Mac/Mac/Views/MvxViewControllerExtensionMethods.cs:24
>     at MvvmCross.Mac.Views.MvxViewControllerAdapter.HandleViewDidLoadCalled (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in /Users/kwl/Projects/Xamarin/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/Mac/Mac/Views/MvxViewControllerAdapter.cs:32
>     at at (wrapper delegate-invoke) :invoke_void_object_EventArgs (object,System.EventArgs)
>     at MvvmCross.Platform.Core.MvxDelegateExtensionMethods.Raise (System.EventHandler eventHandler, System.Object sender) [0x00000] in V:\Xamarin\MvvmCross\MvvmCross\Platform\Platform\Core\MvxDelegateExtensionMethods.cs:16
>     at MvvmCross.Platform.Mac.Views.MvxEventSourceViewController.ViewDidLoad () [0x00000] in /Users/kwl/Projects/Xamarin/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/Platform/Mac/Views/MvxEventSourceViewController.cs:81
>     at MvvmCross.Platform.Mac.Views.MvxEventSourceViewController.LoadView () [0x00006] in /Users/kwl/Projects/Xamarin/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/Platform/Mac/Views/MvxEventSourceViewController.cs:52
>     at at (wrapper managed-to-native) AppKit.NSApplication:NSApplicationMain (int,string[])
>     at AppKit.NSApplication.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00041] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1381/3afb4af5/source/maccore/src/AppKit/NSApplication.cs:94
>     at TipCalc.Mac.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00007] in /Users/mac/Downloads/MvvmCross-Samples-master/TipCalc/TipCalc.Mac/Main.cs:10

Comment: Hi! Did you find answer?